# Magnitude Proper Accelaration Changes Under Coordinate Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, acceleration

Rindler transformation are studied in the book of Carroll in Section 9.5. He starts from the Minkowski metric and a trajectory with uniform acceleration given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    t(\tau) &= \frac{1}{\alpha}\sinh\left(\alpha\tau\right)\,, \\
    x(\tau) &= \frac{1}{\alpha}\cosh\left(\alpha\tau\right)\,.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Notice that the magnitude of the accelaration ($a^{\mu} = d^{2}x^{\mu}/d\tau^{2}$) is given by
$$ \sqrt{a_{\mu}a^{\mu}} = \alpha\,,$$
which is uniform. Next, he considers a coordinate transformation
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    t &= \frac{1}{a}e^{a\xi}\sinh\left(a\eta\right)\,, \\
    x &= \frac{1}{a}e^{a\xi}\cosh\left(a\eta\right)\,,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
such that the trajectory gets transformed into
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \eta(\tau) &= \frac{\alpha}{a}\tau\,, \\
    \xi(\tau) &= \frac{1}{a}\log\frac{a}{\alpha}\,.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
By calculating the magnitude of the acceleration in the transformed frame, you obtain zero. However, as far as I know, this quantity is a scalar, meaning that it stays invariant under a coordinate transformation. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are running into is here

> Notice that the magnitude of the accelaration ($a^{\mu} = d^{2}x^{\mu}/d\tau^{2}$) is given by
> $$ \sqrt{a_{\mu}a^{\mu}} = \alpha\,,$$
> which is uniform

In your expression $$a^{\mu} = \frac{d^{2}x^{\mu}}{d\tau^{2}}$$ you have used the ordinary derivative $d$. You need to use the [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative) along the curve, $D$. So $$a^{\mu} = \frac{D^{2}x^{\mu}}{D\tau^{2}}$$ You "got away" with it in the inertial frame because in the inertial frame the covariant derivative $D$ is the same as the ordinary derivative $d$ because all of the Christoffel symbols are zero. However, in the Rindler frame the Christoffel symbols are non-zero so the two derivatives differ. Meaning that in the Rindler frame $$a^{\mu} = \frac{D^{2}x^{\mu}}{D\tau^{2}}=\alpha$$ while $$a^{\mu} \ne \frac{d^{2}x^{\mu}}{d\tau^{2}}=0$$

Comment: Great. Thank you. Can you please elaborate on why then one prefers to work in the Rindler frame?

Comment: @Kabouter9 The only reason to prefer one frame over another is convenience. Whether that is convenience in describing the problem or in solving it